# Google Forms Correct/Incorrect Feedback

Tags: forms, google-forms

I am creating a quiz and I want the answer feedback to be different for correct answers and incorrect answers.  The answer format is "short answer".  I am not seeing a way to enter different answer feedback.  If I choose a different answer format like multiple choice I can provide a correct answer feedback and a different answer feedback.  With the short answer I can provide answer feedback, but both correct and incorrect answers see the same feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks a rhetorical question regarding the provision of answer feedback to various type types of question in Google Forms. The OP may wish to provide feedback or a feature request to Google.

So far as *why* Google Forms limited answer feedback, permit me to speculate:

A `multiple choice` question will, by definition, include a list of optional answers to the question. Of these, at least one optional answer **must** be "correct" and at least one optional answer must be "incorrect". Since the options are known in advance, feedback can be tailored to the specific options.

In the case of a `short answer` question, only the "correct" answer can be known with certainty; the number, and range, of "incorrect" answers is unpredictable. Thus, in providing answer feedback, nothing is gained by speculating about why "incorrect" answers are wrong except to the extent of explaining *why* the "correct" answer **must** be the preferred answer.